# How to populate an array with an array inside and a variable? ANGULAR/ typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, sorting, frontend

this sound stupid but i struggle with this, yesterday i needed to do an array and got stuck.

Lets see what i'm saying.

I need populate an array like this

```js
fatherArray=[
  { 
    tagName: '',
    list:[]  
  }
]
```

fatherArray.push() don't work if i don't have this object already ready
I have a bunch of lists and tags, so IE: 'i need to see if someone on the lists are rock, and populate the tag with rock, and with a list of this people' ( **this i already did, i only need to populate the array like bellow** )

**so, how to populate this array? i need to populate to something like this**

```js
fatherArray=[
  { 
    tagName: 'rock',
    list:[iron,metallica,etc]  
  },
  { 
    tagName: 'pop',
    list:[madona,britney]  
  },
  { 
    tagName: 'hip hop',
    list:[travis,lild,etc]  
  },
  { 
    tagName: 'bla bla bla',
    list:[bla,bla,bla,bla]  
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following

```
let newArray: string[] = ['iron','metallica','etc'];

fatherArray.forEach(item => { 
  if (item.tagName === 'rock') {
    item.list = item.list.concat(newArray);
  }
}
```

you need to get access to the inner array to populate it

also if you need to add the object to the fatherArray you can also do something like this

```
let newObj: any = {
  tagName: 'rock',
  list: ['iron','metallica','etc'],
};

fatherArray.push(newObj);
```

Comment: thank you man, i tried something like this and don't get it... but this seems to work. I can see how to do now, thank u